# How to show spinner only if data are fetched from Http service?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, ionic-framework

I have to show a spinner only during http service call, and dismiss it when my component receives data.

I wrote a little cache service in order to fetch data from http service only the first time, and load that data from the cache during every other call, avoiding to call another time the http service.

The service is working as expected,but what if I'd like to show the spinner only during the http call and not when data are fetched from cache?

This is my component's code, it works when getReviewsCategory(this.id) method of my service calls http service, but when it fetches from cache the spinner is never dismissed.
Data are loaded in correct way in the background, but the spinner keeps going.

presentLoading() method is in ngOnInit so it's called everytime, what if I want to call it only when data are fetched from cache? How my component could know it?

```
    ngOnInit() {
       this.presentLoading();
       this.CategoryCtrl();
     }

     CategoryCtrl() {
       this.serverService.getReviewsCategory(this.id)
       .subscribe((data) => {
         this.category_sources = data['value'];
         this.stopLoading();
       });
     }

     async presentLoading() {
       const loadingController = this.loadingController;

       const loadingElement = await loadingController.create({
         spinner: 'crescent',
       });
       return await loadingElement.present()
     }

     async stopLoading() {
       return await this.loadingController.dismiss();
     }

   }
```

EDIT1: this is the CacheService:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class CachingService {

      constructor() { }

      private _cache = {};

      isCashed(url: string) {
        return this._cache[url];
      }

      getData(url: string) {
        return this._cache[url];
      }

      setData(url) {
        return (data) => {
          if (data && (data instanceof Error) === false) {
            this._cache[url] = data;
          };
        }
      }

      reset() {
        this._cache = {};
      }
    }
```

And this is the server service's method:

```
     getReviewsCategory(cat_id) : Observable<any> {
      if (this._c.isCashed(url)) {
            return of(this._c.getData(url));
          }else{
            var modeapp = window.sessionStorage.modeapp;
            var typemodeapp = typeof(window.sessionStorage.modeapp);
            if (modeapp === "online") {
              let promise = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
                this.httpNative.get(url, {}, {}).
                then((data) => {
                  let mydata = JSON.parse(data.data);
                  console.log("Data from HTTP: ");
                  console.log(mydata);
                  resolve(mydata);
                }, (error) => {
                  console.log("error in HTTP");
                  reject(error.error);
               }
              );
            });
              var observable = from(promise);
          }
        }
        return observable
        .pipe(
          tap(this._c.setData(url))
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you're returning an observable from the service, you can try the following to see if this helps.

```
     CategoryCtrl() {
       this.serverService.getReviewsCategory(this.id)
       .subscribe((data) => {
         this.category_sources = data['value'];
         this.stopLoading();
       },
       (error) => console.log(error),
       () => this.stopLoading(); // This always execute
     );}
```

Docs: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-subscribe

However, I believe the problem may come from the object you're calling `.dismiss()` 
 from. You should be calling dismiss on the instance of the element and not the object itself.

```
let loadingElement: Loading = null;

async presentLoading() {
   const loadingController = this.loadingController;
   this.loadingElement = await loadingController.create({
     spinner: 'crescent',
   });
   return await loadingElement.present()
}

async stopLoading() {
   return await this.loadingElement.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...I don't understand this, the observable this.serverService.getReviewsCategory(this.id) emits a value whether the value comes from http service call or from cache so how could I distinguish them?

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about them if both return values are observables. Which makes me think that maybe the issue is in the order of operations. Getting those values from the cache may be too fast and the app may be calling the `stopLoading()` code before the `presentLoading()`. Couple of things you may try: verify that `this.category_sources` is still empty before calling create spinner and/or remove all those async/await from the `presentLoading()` method. Only add async/awaits in code you expect Promises or you know are asynchronous

Comment: okay but what if I'd like to set a spinner only when I fetch data from Http service? If data are in the cache they're loaded immediately so I don't want to show any spinner in that case

Comment: could it be calling stop before presentLoading() even if in the ngOnInit() method present is called first? Then, the subscription send values whether they're from cache or from httpservice so this.category_sources is always empty before calling getReviewsCategory() and filled up then, isn't it? So I don't know where in the code I should distinguish where data come from...

Comment: About the spinner using HTML element, the problem is the same...I could set up a variable checking if loading or not, but where should I do it? In my component is there a way I can know if data come from cache or from Http service?

Comment: You can check where the data comes from, but adding checks for this would add more code and won't solve the problem. Your code should not care about whether the data comes from the cache or the DB. Also, there's no guarantee that `presentLoading()` is finished before `CategoryCtrl()` starts executing, as it's an **asynchronous** function. The only way to guarantee this would be to `await this.presentLoading()` or, because it returns a promise, do something like `this.presentLoading().then(res => {this.CategoryCtrl();}`.

Comment: I've updated my solution above. I didn't notice this was a common construct in Ionic framework and thought it was regular angular.

Comment: Man I don't know how to thank you! Using .then on this.presentLoading() works, the spinner shows for a bunch of milliseconds and then dismiss, while if I use the http service to fetch data it tooks more time. It's not properly the behaviour I was looking for, because I'd like to not show at all the spinner in the cache case, but this is surely much better than what I had before!

Comment: The only way I can think of doing that would be to have a variable in your service, not tied to observables, that you can store a boolean that will tell your components if you have cached data or not. I understand that having a spinner display for milliseconds can look ugly, but keep in mind that you are still performing asynchronous operations, so you are really fetching data in the background. Maybe this could also give _good impresion_ to the users: "Woah your app loads VERY FAST". They will let you know.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm going to leave the spinner in both cases, I just worry I'm using setTimeout() in a bad way, I don't understand very well how should I choose timing for every function...thanks again tho :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) class to intercept all http calls, and in the intercept method, you can stop and start a spinner.

Broadly speaking, the structure is:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Start the spinner.
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
        map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                // Stop the spinner
            }
            return event;
        })
    );
```